# Why common url shorteners use random string instead of random word combinations

Tags: url-shortener

I am working on a url shortener project and I am wondering why won't the common services use random combination of words? It would be easier to remember and not hard to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about making the links easier to read. It is about making them *shorter*.